# Make clients to download InstallShield PreRequisites from Internet

Tags: installshield, prerequisites, installshield-2010

My installshield project uses custom prerequisites to install .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile and Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0 client package.

I want to let clients to donwload .Net Framework and Sync Framework directly from the Internet so that our installer is small. But I cant see a way to this.

If you could give some advices or example, it would be most appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In the Installation Designer, Go to the Media Folder, Select Releases from the Left Pane. On the right pane, under the releases Root tree note, select the Released Child node under this, then the next node under this that is the actual release type (the node above the folders that have the disk image, logs, reports and Validations folders).

Then on the Setup.exe tab for this, find the "InstallShield Prerequisites Location" property and set this to "Download From The Web".

Answer (score 0):

I found a step to solve it on the way of release installer

Comment: am having the same problem, can you help me with your solution.